Why aren't Navigation buttons working correctly after Table is updated?
My navigation buttons work well, except if I update the data on the Form. If I go into a record from the Form, and alter the data, Update the Record, then I use the Next / Previous button, then go back to the original modified data, it hasn't been updated. But if I go to First record or Last Record, then use then Next / Previous buttons to go back to the record with the updated data, the form shows the correctly modified data.
On the First and Last buttons I use Index = Table.Rows.Count on the Next / Previous I use Index -= 1 and Index += 1.
Can someone please advise of direct me if I can use the Index = Table.Rows.Count on the Next / Previous buttons?
Code below.
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Image
Imports Windows.Win32.System
Imports System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335
Imports System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader

Public Class FrmStaffDetails
    Dim Table As New DataTable()
    Dim Position As Integer
    Dim Index As Integer = 0
    Dim PageRows As Integer
    Dim UserStatus As String
    Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand

    Private Sub FrmStaffDetails_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CountRows()
        ShowData(Index)
    End Sub

    Public Sub CountRows()
        Dim Con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SimpleMaintenanceSystem;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True")
        Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand("select count(*) from Staff", Con)
        Dim Count1 As Integer

        Con.Open()
        Count1 = Convert.ToString(Cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        PageRows = Math.Ceiling(Count1)
        TextBox2.Text = PageRows
        Con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private conString As String = "Data Source=LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SimpleMaintenanceSystem;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
    Private Sub ShowData(Position As Integer)
        Using Con As New SqlConnection(conString),
            Cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Staff order by StaffID", Con),
            Adaptor As New SqlDataAdapter(Cmd)
            Adaptor.Fill(Table)
        End Using

        If Position < 0 OrElse Position >= Table.Rows.Count Then Return

        TxtStaffID.Text = Table.Rows(Position)(0).ToString()
        TxtStaffFirstName.Text = Table.Rows(Position)(1).ToString()
        TxtStaffLastName.Text = Table.Rows(Position)(2).ToString()
        TxtStaffAddress.Text = Table.Rows(Position)(3).ToString()
        TxtStaffCity.Text = Table.Rows(Position)(4).ToString()
        TxtStaffState.Text = Table.Rows(Position)(5).ToString()
        TxtStaffPostCode.Text = Table.Rows(Position)(6).ToString()
        TxtStaffPhoneNumber.Text = Table.Rows(Position)(7).ToString()

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCancel.Click
        Dim Con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SimpleMaintenanceSystem;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True")
        Con.Dispose()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnFirst_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnFirst.Click
        Index = Table.Rows.Count - 0
        ShowData(Index)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnNext.Click
        If TxtStaffID.Text = PageRows Then
            MessageBox.Show("At LAST Record!", "Error!",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            ShowData(Index)
        Else
            Index += 1
            ShowData(Index)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrevious.Click
        If TxtStaffID.Text = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("At FIRST Record!", "Error!",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            ShowData(Index)
        Else

            Index -= 1
            ShowData(Index)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnLast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLast.Click
        Index = Table.Rows.Count - 1
        ShowData(Index)
    End Sub


    Private Sub BtnUpdateData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdateData.Click
        Dim Con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SimpleMaintenanceSystem;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True")
        Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Staff ORDER BY StaffID", Con)
        Dim adaptor As New SqlDataAdapter(Cmd)

        If Con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Con.Close()
        End If
        Con.Open()
        adaptor.Update(Table)

        Try
            Dim rowsAffected As Integer
            Cmd = Con.CreateCommand
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            Cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Staff SET StaffFirstname=@FirstName
            , StaffLastName = @LastName
            , StaffAddress = @Address
            , StaffCity = @city
            , StaffState = @State
            , StaffPostCode = @PostCode
            , StaffPhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber WHERE Staffid = @StaffId"

            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@StaffID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TxtStaffID.Text
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TxtStaffFirstName.Text
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TxtStaffLastName.Text
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TxtStaffAddress.Text
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TxtStaffCity.Text
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TxtStaffState.Text
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Postcode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TxtStaffPostCode.Text
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TxtStaffPhoneNumber.Text

            rowsAffected = Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

            If rowsAffected > 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Data Updated Succesfully")
            ElseIf MessageBox.Show("Data UNSUCCESFULLY Updated") Then
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally

        End Try
        adaptor.Dispose()
        Con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtStaffLastName.TextChanged
        TextBox3.Text = PageRows + 1 'This is used in the add a new record function
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnInsertNewData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnInsertNewData.Click
        Dim Con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SimpleMaintenanceSystem;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True")

        Con.Open()
        Cmd = Con.CreateCommand()
        'TxtStaffFirstName.Text = "Add"
        'TxtStaffLastName.Text = "New"
        'TxtStaffAddress.Text = "Staff"
        'TxtStaffCity.Text = "Member"
        'TxtStaffState.Text = ""
        'TxtStaffPostCode.Text = ""
        'TxtStaffPhoneNumber.Text = ""

        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into staff (StaffID) values ('" + TextBox3.Text + "')"
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Dispose()
        CountRows()
        ShowData(Index)
        MessageBox.Show("New Staff Member Inserted")
    End Sub
End Class


That code is very wrong. You keep getting all the same data over and over. Just get the data once. Populate a DataTable, bind that to a BindingSource and bind that to your controls. To navigate, simply call MoveNext or MovePrevious on the BindingSource. BTW, the Fill method returns the number of records retrieved.

You're vulnerable to SQL Injection. what happens if an user enters in TextBox3 the value:
Jhon '); DROP ALL TABLES; GO; --

Textbox3 is a locked item and not visible , it only displays a hidden number, thanks for the heads up

I will search how to create and use the datatable and binding source, I'm not familiar with that, thanks

Also all your querying is happening on your UI thread. You could look into some strategies such as BackgroundWorker, multithreading with Thread, and Async/Await

Also put Option Strict On at the top of your code and figure out why TextBox3.Text = PageRows + 1 now has a compile error

Also either use Try..Finally properly to dispose your IDisposable sql stuff, or use a Using block to do it. But do it

If TextBox3 is hidden then why not just use a string variable? Don't store your state on the UI

I didn't know about string variables, but I sorry I meant to clarify, I'm not a programmer, I like learning how to program after 48 years of toolmaking, and I was looking here for guidance, thanks I will look into string variables

Thanks djv I will take on board everything you've suggested, and I will try to educate myself more on these items

Please see BindingNavigator Control and the In This Section links. See also BindingSource Component. That will help you to understand and refactor your code. Enjoy reading.

If you care to read some more, please see Option Strict.

Thanks Dr.null I will take everything on board and learn from it, thanks heaps to you and djv your patience and expert advice is greatly appreciated
